# Android ValueAnimator EditText choppy animation

Tags: android, animation, android-edittext

I'm creating sliding animation for my views using Value Animator. Problem is, when subviews is EditText animation is choppy. Code:

```
private ValueAnimator SlideAnimator(int start,int end, View mView)
    {
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.OfInt(start, end);
        animator.SetDuration(2500);
        animator.Update +=
            (object sender, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e) => { 
           var value = (int)animator.AnimatedValue;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mView.LayoutParameters;
            layoutParams.Height = value;
            mView.LayoutParameters=layoutParams;
            mView.RequestLayout();
    }; 
    return animator;

  if (wrappedChildren[position].Visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {
            int finalHeight = wrappedChildren[position].Height;
            ValueAnimator mAnimator = SlideAnimator(finalHeight, 0, wrappedChildren[position]);
            mAnimator.Start();
            mAnimator.AnimationEnd += (sender, args) => 
            {
                SetSectionVisibility(position, ViewStates.Gone);
            };
        }
        else
        {
            int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);
            int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);
            wrappedChildren[position].Measure(widthSpec,heightSpec);
            int measuredHeight = wrappedChildren[position].MeasuredHeight;
            ValueAnimator mAnimator = SlideAnimator(0, measuredHeight,wrappedChildren[position]);
            mAnimator.Start();
            SetSectionVisibility(position, ViewStates.Visible);

        }
```

wrappedChildren[position] is View that holds EditText subview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it on emulator or real device? It may be sluggish just because of emulator...